# Linear Regression: Multiplying the coefficient by the mean

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I have a coefficient that represents per minute of watching videos. I am measuring against the dependent variable of exam scores.

I also have the mean of the minutes of watching videos from descriptives. What might be the problem if I multiply the coefficient by the mean?

I am hoping to be able to report an 'average' benefit/impact. aka x% decrease or improvement in exam scores

If someone has examples would be great too!

[image]

Comment: Is this from a validated linear model? Did it have an intercept?

Comment: Thanks, yes i pasted the table in the question. My goal is to be able to report on average the watching of videos against the dependent (eg exam scores).